# WordPress Theme "ERROR: The theme defines itself as its parent theme. Please check the Template header."

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress Website's Themes Area I am getting strange message - "ERROR: The theme defines itself as its parent theme. Please check the Template header."
[image]
I Cannot Figure out what is Wrong. Please help me.

The **header.php** files code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>"/>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/Images/favicon.gif" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/Font/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body class="custom-background">
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="header">
      <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
            <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="fortuneshop9999" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--Google Translator-->
    <div id="google_translate_element">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'nl', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE }, 'google_translate_element');
                }
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
    <!--End-->
    <div id="nav">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'container' => '', 'menu_class' => 'mainMenu' ) );?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="subnav">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu-facebook">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-twitter">
          <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-email">
          <a href="mailto:fortuneshop9999@gmail.com" target="_blank">Email</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-pinterest">
          <a href="http://www.pinterest.com" target="_blank">Pinterest</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>/">
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars($s, 1); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search here"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value=""/>
      </form>
    </div>
```

The **style.css** code is:

```
    /*
 Theme Name:   Yogi7
 Theme URI:    http://www.myotcworld.com/website-package.aspx
 Author:       Yogi
 Author URI:   http://www.myotcworld.com/website-package.aspx
 Template:     yogi7
 Version:      1.0.0
*/
body.custom-background {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background: url("Images/seamless-stone-background.jpg" ); /*background:#FDE6E0;*/
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    padding: 0;
}

#header {
    width: 960px;
    height: 285px;
    background: url("Images/header.png") no-repeat;
}
....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed the **Template: yogi7** from the top of my **styles.css** file of the theme. And this solved the problem.

This is how the **styles.css** look now.

```
/*
Theme Name:   Yogi7
Theme URI:    http://www.myotcworld.com/website-package.aspx
Author:       Yogi
Author URI:   http://www.myotcworld.com/website-package.aspx
Version:      1.0.0
*/
body.custom-background {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background: url("Images/seamless-stone-background.jpg" ); /*background:#FDE6E0;*/
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    padding: 0;
}
......
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Also fixed the issue for me, I've developed a theme in the past and it worked by adding the 'Template: name' tag, never mind anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
/*
  Theme Name:   Yogi7 Child
  Theme URI:    http://www.myotcworld.com/website-package.aspx
  Description:  Yogi Child Theme
  Author:       Yogi
  Author URI:   http://example.com
  Template:     <REPLACE WITH YOUR DIRECTORY NAME OF THE PARENT THEME>
  Version:      1.0.0
  License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
  License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
  Text Domain:  yogi-child
*/
```

The `Template` line corresponds to the directory name of the parent theme. The parent theme in example case is the *Twenty Fifteen theme*, so the Template will be *twentyfifteen*. You may be working with a different theme, so adjust accordingly.

Note: Replace *Template* with your directory name of the parent theme.

More you can read form official docs [Codex Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check on style.css file there its defined if a theme is going to be parent or child theme,

/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fourteen Child
Template: twentyfourteen
*/

see if theme name and template once check!

Comment: My theme is not childtheme it is custom theme. I have added the style.css code on my question. Please have a look to it and please tell me if I need to do any change on it. Thank you !!

Comment: then remove the line `Template:...` in style.css

Comment: did it solve for you? may be folder name, or style.css there can't be any other reason i think.