# how can i get wordpress to understand my custom theme is not a child theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I had finally finished building a custom theme from scratch after weeks of work, and accidentally clicked on Appearance > Themes. Suddenly the theme is "broken" and won't load in the Themes dialog. I tried renaming the theme folder, I tried editing the headers, deactivating plugins, and nothing works. Everything worked perfectly until I hit the darned Themes link. It says, "AAW Custom Theme   The parent theme is missing. Please install the "AAW" parent theme." But there is no parent theme because it's not a child theme. I have been trying to research the problem but can only find help with child themes. I'm at a loss. How do I get Wordpress to understand that this is not a child theme?

Comment: Your theme's CSS header should contain information such as 'Child theme' and parent theme location. You can edit those.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said above, I checked that everything is correct in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Update: For others running into this issue: this helped: [WordPress Theme "ERROR: The theme defines itself as its parent theme. Please check the Template header."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034914/wordpress-theme-error-the-theme-defines-itself-as-its-parent-theme-please-che)

Try removing the template tag from the header.